# How to add a user/login Link to the Maintenance Mode page?

Tags: theming, users, maintenance-mode

I have my site in Maintenance Mode. I know I can get to my login page by going to http://example.com/login .

My client wants a login link on the Maintenance Mode page (when in this mode). Before I say "no this is not possible", I am wondering if this is possible. I could add this to the Maintenance template page right? I already have a custom Maintenance Mode page.

EDIT: Where the http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-theme-the-user-login-page-in-maintenance-mode
solution works, its not what I want. All I want is a link to the user login page displayed on the Maintenance Page.

I did try this: I added html to the maintenance php template:  `<div><a href="/user/login" >Login</a></div>`

HOWEVER this only show a link that was NOT clickable. Also how would I get to the User login page if I am testing this on a test server, but the domain will be different than on the test server. Change the domain once on the production server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to. You can create a maintenance page template similar to any other in Drupal, "maintenance-page.tpl.php". However, to get that to work you probably have to make some changes to your template.php file.

More info can be found here: http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-theme-the-user-login-page-in-maintenance-mode although I believe that example is from Drupal 6, but the idea should be fairly similar for Drupal 7 as well.

Comment: The only issue I have your suggestion that it prompts user on maintenance page for user login credentials when all I want is a link.

Comment: Ok as a temp solution I just added HTML to maintenance-page.tpl.php.

Comment: @BenjaminJones I don't see why you wouldn't just be able to add a textual link then on the maintenance page to /user/login just as with any standard href link.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `maintenance-page.tpl.php` file is indeed a vaid approach for this. However if you use that approach, there are **two maintenance page** files that you should create. You can duplicate your theme's page.tpl.php twice and name them:

- `maintenance-page.tpl.php`: This file controls the page that is displayed when the site is in "maintenance mode" but ***the database connection and database are still functioning correctly***.
- `maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php`: This file controls the page that is displayed ***when Drupal cannot access the database (for whatever reason)***.

For more details on this, and related changes in `settings.php`, refer to the community documentation about [Theming the Drupal maintenance page](https://www.drupal.org/node/195435).